# How to simple Regex with ls

Tags: string, ls

I'd like to list contents of several folders in one line. 
ie `/etc/dovecot/keys` and `/etc/postfix/keys` 
 and I'm not sure how to use Regex.
I came as far as doing the following:

```
ls /etc/[d,p]*/keys
```

Which actually returns those two folders, but only because no other folder starts with `d` or `p`.  How can I put entire folder name in Regex ie `[postfix|dovecot]` 
Thanks

Comment: Duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44754/listing-with-ls-and-regular-expression

Comment: Hi @Jorn I've seen that post, but there are only alternating 1 character (or patterns), I'd like to have an 'OR' for entire word.